# Randomise blocks of values

Tags: r, data.table, dcast

I have a dataset where I have several variables - measurements of length, width etc - and a grouping variable - line. I want to randomise the data in such a way that the between line variances remain, but line covariances among variables are broken.

Using iris as an example, here I can get the blocks of values for each species to stay together by the grouping variable of species and get randomised to new species for each trait individually - exactly as I want - but it is also putting NAs in the data. How can I get this to reduce so that the shape is the same as the original data?

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(21)

dtIris <- data.table(id = rep(1:9, times = 1), iris[c(1:3, 51:53, 101:103), ])

dtIris 

dcast(
  melt(dtIris, id.vars = c('id', 'Species'))[
    melt(dtIris, id.vars = c('id', 'Species'))[, 
      .('Species' = unique(Species), 'new' = sample(unique(Species))), by = variable], 
    on = c('Species', 'variable')][, -c('Species')], 
  ... ~ variable, value.vars = 'value')
```

This is putting the data in long format, sampling unique values of species for each trait, merging that back onto the data in long format, then spreading it back to wide format. It is leaving NAs where new != Species.

```
    id        new Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
 1:  1     setosa           NA         3.5          1.4          NA
 2:  1  virginica          5.1          NA           NA         0.2
 3:  2     setosa           NA         3.0          1.4          NA
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, hence posting an answer. The reason why you have `NA`'s is because you have sampled the data for each `variable` hence the proportion between your `new` variable and `id` have changed.

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- melt(dtIris, id.vars = c('id', 'Species'))

dt2 <- dt1[dt1[,.('Species' = unique(Species), 'new' = sample(unique(Species))), 
                by = variable], on = c('Species', 'variable')]
```

Previously what you had was

```
table(dt2$Species, dt2$id)

#             1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#  setosa     4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  versicolor 0 0 0 4 4 4 0 0 0
#  virginica  0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 4
```

and now what you have is :

```
table(dt2$new, dt2$id)
#             1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#  setosa     1 1 1 0 0 0 3 3 3
#  versicolor 3 3 3 0 0 0 1 1 1
#  virginica  0 0 0 4 4 4 0 0 0
```

As you can see previously every `id` had only one `Species` in it but after sampling it is not true (see `id = 1` has both `"setosa"` and `"versicolor"` whereas previously it had only `"setosa"`). There is no way `id = 1` can have `new` variable in 1 row when their values are different.

Comment: Thanks - I know that is the cause. I should have said, the id column can be dropped.

Comment: `id` is just an representation to show which value will be in which row. If you drop this `id` column you need to have another `id` column to clarify which value will go where in the wide format. In `dt2`, there is same `Species` column for each `id` value hence when you cast data to wide using `Species` column you'll get the data in the way you want. The same is not true for `new` column where you have different `new` values for each `id`. If this explanation is not clear could you please take `dt2` from my answer and show your expected output using that?